# Xgboost Num_class in R

Tags: r, xgboost

a very quick question that is confusing me. I'm new to r and predictive modelling and I'm currently using xgboost for a binary classification model. I'm a little confused about the num_class parameter in that when I set it on 1 I have a normal output and it works fine. However, when it is set to 2 it doubles the rows of data in the prediction but weirdly the accuracy improves. 
For binary classification is the parameter supposed to be 1 or 2 and if 2 why do I get double the rows?

Comment: Welcome. You'll get better answers if you share the code you are having trouble with.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to set num_class for binary classification.

If you refer the docmentation , you'll find -

> num_class set the number of classes. To use **only** with multiclass
>   objectives
>
> multi:softmax set xgboost to do multiclass classification using the
>   softmax objective. Class is represented by a number and should be from
>   0 to num_class - 1.